# Tabulator from existing datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, tabulator

I'm generating a tabulator table with a groupBy method from an already filtered datatable (from DataTable.js) with date range and parameters already defined. The new tabulator table is working perfectly fine but takes the whole data regardless of the filters already applied to the table I need to create the groupby from. My original datatable is:

```
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable();
```

and with the filters is 20 lines long. When creating the tabulator from that datatable it takes the whole data. Is there a way to reuse the same filtered table already existent to create a tabulator groupBy approach?

here's the code of my tabulator:

```
if(table!=null){
        $('#datatable').DataTable().destroy();
    }
    
    var tableTab = new Tabulator('#datatable',{
    groupToggleElement:"header",
    height:"100%",
    virtualDomBuffer: "100%",
    layout:"fitColumns",
    pagination:"local",
    //paginationSize:false,
    movableRows:false,
    groupBy:"Id",
    groupStartOpen:false,
    columns:[
        {title:"a", field:"a", width:200},
        {title:"b", field:"b"},
        {title:"c", field:"c"},
        {title:"d", field:"d"},
        {title:"Id", field:"Id"},
        {title:"e", field:"e"},
        {title:"CreatedDate", field:"CreatedDate"},
    ],
});
tableTab.setFilter($('#select').val(), $('datepickerStart').datepicker, $( "#datepickerEnd").datepicker());
```

IS there a way to create the new Tabulator from the filtered table.DataTable() and not from the whole '#datatable' with the full data?
Example:

```
select only a's in the last 10 days and groupBy b's.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ***initialFilter*** option to set filters on the table when it loads, so you shouldnt need to call the ***setFilter*** function:

```js
var tableTab = new Tabulator('#datatable',{
    groupToggleElement:"header",
    height:"100%",
    layout:"fitColumns",
    pagination:"local",
    movableRows:false,
    groupBy:"Id",
    groupStartOpen:false,
    initialFilter:[
        {field:"a", type:"=", value:5000}  //set an initial filter that will only show rows with an a value of 5000
    ],
    columns:[
        {title:"a", field:"a", width:200},
        {title:"b", field:"b"},
        {title:"c", field:"c"},
        {title:"d", field:"d"},
        {title:"Id", field:"Id"},
        {title:"e", field:"e"},
        {title:"CreatedDate", field:"CreatedDate"},
    ],
});
```

You will need to provide three properties for each initial filter, the field name of the column you want to filter, the [Filter Function](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/filter#func) and the value to filter for

Comment: is it possible to create the table starting from an already existent datatable? The original one is already filtered, I just need to groupby using a tabulator object the original datatable

Comment: and how can I filter the groupBy between a date range?

Comment: I already have 2 datepicker elements and I can sort the datatable between two dates, how can I implement that function in a filter inside the tabulator object?

Comment: You can pass the data from the datatable into tabulator, but you cant pass a datatable object into Tabulator and expect it to work no.

Comment: to group by a range of values you would need to pass a function to the groupBy property that contains the logic to work out our range, full details can be found here http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/group#setup-field

Comment: You would need to use a filter function to achieve this, as per the filter documentation: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/filter#func